# Laravel data not passing to Dropdown box

Tags: laravel

i am creating the dropdownbox in laravel i need to fetch data from the database to the dropdownbox. i have done it but i ran into the problem with

```
Attempt to read property "id" on string
```

what i tried so far i attached below.some one help me to solve this problem please.
Model

**Batch**

```
class Batch extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'batches';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'course_id', 'start_date'];
    use HasFactory;

    public function course()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
    }
}
```

**BatchController**

```
public function create(): View
{
    $courses = Course::pluck('name','id');
    return view('batches.create', compact('courses'));

}
```

**batch view**

```
<select name="course_id" id="course_id" class="form-control">
 @foreach($courses as $item)
<option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name}}</option>
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $item is a string (the name of the course) rather than an object, it throws an error.

To fix this, modify your blade file so that it uses the key (course id) and value (course name) together directly, like in:

```html
<select name="course_id" id="course_id" class="form-control">
    @foreach($courses as $id => $name)
        <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```